# How do I add function synonyms in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, function, scripting, synonym

My `~/.bashrc` file contains several custom-made functions and I would like some of them to have synonyms. For example, I have the following identical functions in this script that I'd to combine by use of synonyms if possible:

```
function pyimmassl {
    pushd /pywiki
    python imagetransfer.py -file:$1.txt -keepname -tofamily:Linux_Wiki -tolang:en
    popd
}

function pyimagemassl {
    pushd /pywiki
    python imagetransfer.py -file:$1.txt -keepname -tofamily:Linux_Wiki -tolang:en
    popd
}
```

Comment: From the `man bash`: `For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.`

Comment: @Narūnas I guess that this is a perfect example of an exception to that rule - it wouldn't make much sense to define a second function that just called the first one with an unmodified set of arguments...

Comment: @NarūnasK I haven't the foggiest what this output means. I am merely a novice at programming, I just know enough to get me by in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an alias:

```
function pyimmassl {
    pushd /pywiki
    python imagetransfer.py -file:$1.txt -keepname -tofamily:Linux_Wiki -tolang:en
    popd
}

alias pyimagemassl=pyimmassl
```

Now you can call the function using either name.